# Does iOS OperationQueue have the same features of Android WorkManager (persistent, multiple tries, ability to see queue and status, network)?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I am looking to use a mechanism, like [Android's WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/), in iOS. I want to submit work to be done, have it run when the network is connected. I also need to see the work in the queue, try a certain number of times, see what the errors were encountered and cancel/re-queue the work.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733614/ios-queue-blocks-in-background-and-execute-when-network-becomes-available) on queueing work in iOS for when the network becomes available, which recommends OperationQueue. [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/u2qplt/is_there_any_equivalent_of_android_workmanager_on/) also mentions OperationQueue. I have also seen [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/77842) on features within URLSession to run in the background which persist.

After the work is done, I need it to update an entity in CoreData as well. All of this I do currently in Android with WorkManager. I can see the full queue, the ones that failed, control the things which need to be in place for them to run (network), restart them or remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Operation queues just manage dependencies between individual operations. Unfortunately, this is cumbersome when the operations wrap work that is, itself, asynchronous, requiring clumsy manual implementation KVC and KVO. Because of all of this, nowadays we would reach for Swift concurrency, which handles all of this far more elegantly. Operation queues were an elegant, though complicated, solution, but are arguably a bit of an anachronism nowadays. For a comparison of Swift concurrency, operation queues, and Combine, see [How To Download Multiple Files Sequentially using `URLSession` `downloadTask` in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322851/1271826).

That having been said, if you want network requests to persist even after the user has left the app, none of those patterns will quite work. For this, we would often reach for a [background `URLSessionConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background). This is ideal for network requests that may take more than a few seconds (e.g., downloading/uploading a huge asset, such as a video) or requests that should be submitted when network connectivity is re-established. The [Downloading files in the background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/) outlines many of the idiosyncratic details. And this pattern works for uploads, too (though there are some specific additional requirements for uploads, specifically that one must upload from a file rather than using the `httpBody`).

In short, I would suggest focusing on background `URLSessionConfiguration`, where an out-of-process daemon will manage the outstanding network requests for you.

Regarding the ability to fetch the list of pending tasks when the user relaunches the app, [`getTasksWithCompletionHandler(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411578-gettaskswithcompletionhandler) returns a list of pending tasks.

Comment: This is very helpful, Rob. Thank you. I don't need the process to complete even after the user has left the app, but I do need them to persist. I just need to make sure that if the user is in a bad cell location, the records eventually get updated AND that afterwards they can update the sync data in the CoreData database. I don't think this changes your recommendation to use URLSessionConfiguration, correct?

Comment: Hmm. It’s a bit more of a horse race in that scenario. You get some of the behaviors that you’re looking for with the background session (e.g., persists, waits for connection, etc.). But it comes at the cost of some complexity (you must use the delegate-based implementation, etc.) and requests are sent out at the discretion of the OS. I guess that on the basis of what you’ve described, it sounds like a tradeoff that you’re willing to make.

Comment: Let me look at it. The Android one worked really well but I remember I had to make a time investment there as well as it was heavily engineered.

Comment: Can you have both background and regular urlsessions in the same app?

Comment: Yes. In addition to your background session, you can have normal `URLSession`, too.

Comment: Ok. I need to figure out how to integrate the `URLSessionConfiguration.background` with what I am doing now `URLSession.shared.data` and any delegate work which needs to be done.

Comment: Also need to see how a bearer token impacts this.

Comment: I think you’ll find that neither the delegate protocol nor the bearer token are really that bad. The bearer token is generally trivial (just setting a `Authorization` header on the `URLRequest`). The delegate pattern is just a matter of correlating the response with the original request (e.g., by URL or by task identifier). The biggest challenge with background sessions is that your app may have been suspended or terminated in the course of the normal app lifespan, so you will want to think about how/if you persist the model data associated with the original request across separate launches.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to plug through it. The only issue with the token is that it is dependent on being logged in (or within the life of the token) so it might be an additional constraint, which would look like configuration setting (e.g. `waitsForValidToken` or login or something like that). I had object which did all this for me w/the authorization so I need to have an option to pass in a URLSession so I can set the delegate there and pass it through.

Comment: I read through what you provided, which was very helpful. Is there any reason a network request cannot be a data task (vs upload or download) and therefore not need specifically a file for `httpBody`? I realize the documentation says a background task is for uploads/downloads, but it's set in the configuration, which means the session object itself can call a `.data`...right?

Comment: I'm not against a file, but I do need to update CoreData with the results from the POST.

Comment: When using background sessions, you use a download task. When your app is relaunched, rather than processing a `Data`, you parse the contents of the file passed back to your app by that local file `URL`. They do this to facilitate the passing of the payload between this system daemon and your app as well as minimize the RAM footprint of these background requests.

Comment: Since I have a body which needs to be delivered in a POST I would use the upload, correct or are you saying I should do a download in order to get the response in a file. I'm starting to think this might not be the right mechanism. The alternative is a process which checks for connectivity and records which need to be uploaded and processes them if they exist.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. Yes, if you are uploading content in POST, then you’d use upload task with file…